# How to properly design classes

Tags: class, database-design

I'm trying to design an application in which a `user` can make multiple `operation`s like add, delete.. `Work station`s or `Application`s from database. How do I design it?

To deal this, I've found two solutions that I couldn't be able to choose the best:

[1st solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtw6F.png), [2nd solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvLzX.png).

Is this right?
Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To think this out a bit, a user can have one or more operations i.e. a one to many relationship with the operation.

An operation can delete one or more Workstations or Applications, again a one to many relationships.

Therefore, I think your 1st solution captures it nicely.

Comment: the association between operation and operation is not `delete` or `add` but `concerns`, the `add` will be saved into the `operation` table as label.

Comment: but it's still a one to many relationship?

Comment: OK, so I still say solution one is my preferred option for the same reason I gave above.

Answer (score 0):

I think solution 1 is better. Solution 2 requires that you insert 2 records in the 2 many-to-many associative tables, for each single operation. This is more complex, and probably unnecessarily so.

In solution 1 the Operation table becomes the only associative table. 1 operation, 1 insert. You may have to have to make some of the referencing keys nullable, depending on your requirements, but this is manageable. Simpler and sufficient for the needs you expressed.

Comment: Thank you so much Frazz!! I wanted to upvote your answer but I haven't the sufficient rate.